# What is wrong with this syntax that works in mysql 5 but doesn't work in mysql 8

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

1064 error in SQL Syntax near '!=guildRank LIMIT 1 END' at line 3

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `DeleteUserGuildAttr`(IN userId INT unsigned, IN guildId 
INT unsigned, IN guildRank SMALLINT unsigned)
BEGIN
     DELETE FROM guildattr WHERE id=userId AND guild_id=guildId AND rank!=guildRank LIMIT 1;
END
```

Comment: `RANK` is now a MySQL (and ANSI SQL) reserved word: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_reserved_words. i.e. it needs to be delimited using back-ticks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL 8.0 added the [`rank()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_rank) window function, so it is now [reserved](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html).

You need to escape it:

```
`rank` <> guildRank
```

for the condition.