# What is missing in my CREATE TABLE in order to work? mySQL 8.X

Tags: mysql, sql, popsql

I was coding using mySQL 5.x and now i switched to 8.x version and i am confused.
What is wrong with this short code ?

[screenshot of my code ]

[image: 1]

Error message

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'rank VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, discipline VARCHAR(1), yr_start INT(11), ' at line 3"

Comment: Please put the code in your question as *text*.

Comment: The stated duplicate definitely does not explain why this works in MySQL 5.7 but not in 8+.

Comment: @GordonLinoff How about this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61411216/10498828? How many times will you answer the same question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`rank` is now a MySQL reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html).  It is used for the `rank()` window function

Use a variant, such as `ranking` instead.

These functions were introduced in MySQL 8.

Answer (score 1):

In case changing your schema is not practical for some reason, you can also use quoted identifier.  By default in MySQL use the backquote character, for example:

```
create table foo (
   `rank` varchar(50)
)
```

should work if you want to port your pre-existing schema from older mysql version without modifying your application logic.

Comment: Oh thanks it's working too ! It's just quite unusual for me to type the ` character with my keyboard.